# how to compare values from previous page to values in the newly opened page in webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to compare the transaction number displayed in the page to the transaction number displayed in the next page after the user has clicked on the Transaction No link.

[image]

I have tried the following:

```
//  -----------------------Selecting values in the form-------------------
// Call the function to select a date from calendar e.g. 2016/04/19        
        ClaimsOnline_fields.pickExpDate("19",4,2016);

// In the Transaction Types dropdown, select a value e.g. "Realtime Transactions Only"
        TransTypesDrop = new Select(drivers.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='type']")));
        TransTypesDrop.selectByVisibleText("Realtime Transactions Only");       

// In the Dataset dropdown, select a value e.g. "5 - DJCJ0005" 
        DatasetDrop = new Select(Utilities.drivers.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='logbook_form']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/fieldset/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]/select")));
        DatasetDrop.selectByVisibleText("5 - DJCJ0005");        

// Click the Show button        
        drivers.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='logbook_form']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/input[1]")).click();

        Utilities.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("html/body/table[2]")));

        batchVal = drivers.findElements(By.className("results"));

//----------------------- Drill into test result --------------------------                        

List<String> all_elements_text=new ArrayList<>();
//        Click the first result
        for(int i=0; i<batchVal.size(); i++ ){

//            Click the Transaction No of the first result
            batchVal.get(1).click();            

//            The next page is opened
            Utilities.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("jqi")));
            Utilities.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("jqi"))); 

            drivers.findElement(By.className("jqidefaultbutton")).click(); 

            Utilities.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("html/body/p")));

            String TransNo = drivers.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/p")).getText();

            Utilities.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("html/body/p")));

//            Add the value from the search result into the array
            all_elements_text.add(batchVal.get(i).getText());

//            get the currently displayed Transaction Num
            String TransNoTrimmed = TransNo.substring(34,48);

//            
            if(all_elements_text.get(1).equals(TransNoTrimmed)){
                System.out.println("Test Passed - Claims Online - Logbook - Drill into Results - Transaction Number matches one displayed in the drilled results i.e. "+TransNoTrimmed);
            }
            break;
        }
```

When I run this I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element
>   reference: element is not attached to the page document
>         (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)
>         (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.10240 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Answer (score 1):

replace the following line.

`batchVal.get(1).click();`

with

`drivers.findElements(By.className("results")).get(i).click();`

to avoid the **StaleElementReferenceException**

what's happening here is, as you have created the object of WebElements and then you are clicking on the that page. Some part of the page changes after click and so the stored element becomes stale, and that's what Webdriver is telling you.

Comment: The problem occurs when I compare data from previous page to the data on the new page after I have drilled in:

if(all_elements_text.get(1).equals(TransNoTrimmed)){
                System.out.println("Test Passed - Claims Online - Logbook - Drill into Results - Transaction Number matches one displayed in the drilled results i.e. "+TransNoTrimmed);
            }

Comment: that the exact place I am telling you the replace the code. if you will store elements in list and then use it, it will throw `StaleElementReferenceException` if even a minor thing has changed on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Just download new chrome extension file for selenium and use selenium 3.